# Assign map <Id,Set<String>> in trigger

Tags: trigger, map, set, after-trigger

I have below code where I need `Map<ID,Set<String>>`, but I am unable to assign that value and it shows error. Can someone please help me?

**Apex Code**
//  User - Terr Name

```
Map<Id,String> Uterr = new Map<Id,String>();
List<Territory> terr = [select Name, Id from Territory];
For(Userterritory ut : [select userId,Territoryid from Userterritory where UserId in: userIds])
{
  for(Territory t: terr)
  { if(t.Id==ut.TerritoryId)
    Uterr.put(ut.UserId,t.Name);
  }

}
    Map<Id,Set<String>> accTerrMap = new Map<Id,Set<String>>();

    for(Account_Team_Member_vod__c con : trigger.new) {

    accTerrMap.put(AccplanAcc.get(con.Account_Plan_vod__c),Uterr.get(con.Team_Member_vod__c));
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: IN this statement the 2nd parameter value must be a List not String: `accTerrMap.put(AccplanAcc.get(con.Account_Plan_vod__c),Uterr.get(con.Team_Member_vod__c));`

Comment: Don't use a loop in a loop: `for(UserTerritory ut: [SELECT UserId, Territory.Name FROM UserTerritory WHERE UserId IN :userIds]) { uterr.put(ut.UserId, ut.Territory.Name); }` or `Map<Id, Territory> terrs = new Map<Id, Territory>([SELECT Name FROM Territory]); for(UserTerritory ut: [SELECT UserId, TerritoryId FROM UserTerritory WHERE UserId IN :userIds]) { if(terrs.containsKey(ut.TerrtitoryId) { uterr.put(ut.UserId, ut.Territory.Name); } }`

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that for `Map<Id, Set<String>>` for every new Id, value (which is Set should be initialised separately, before records are added into it.

For example:

```
Map<Id,String> Uterr = new Map<Id,String>();
List<Territory> terr = [SELECT Name, Id FROM Territory];
for(Userterritory ut : [SELECT UserId, Territoryid 
                        FROM Userterritory
                        WHERE UserId in :userIds]) {
    for(Territory t: terr) { 
        if(t.Id==ut.TerritoryId) {
            Uterr.put(ut.UserId,t.Name);
        }
    }
}

Map<Id,Set<String>> accTerrMap = new Map<Id,Set<String>>();

for(Account_Team_Member_vod__c con : Trigger.new) {
    Id key = AccplanAcc.get(con.Account_Plan_vod__c);
    if (!accTerrMap.contains(key)) { 
        // In case if there are no records for given key in Map 
        //    -- add empty set
        accTerrMap.put(key, new Set<String>());
    }
    //Add Team_Member_vod__c into corresponding set (which exists for sure)
    accTerrMap.get(key).add(Uterr.get(con.Team_Member_vod__c));
}
```

P.S.
Also, as mentioned by [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) in comments, it possible to avoid double for loop in first part of the code by querying all the territory data in one request

> SELECT Id, Territory.Name FROM UserTerritory WHERE UserId IN :userIds

As a result, code above will look like next:

```
Map<Id,String> Uterr = new Map<Id,String>();
for(Userterritory ut : [SELECT UserId, Territory.Name 
                            FROM UserTerritory
                            WHERE UserId in :userIds]) {
    Uterr.put(ut.UserId,ut.Territory.Name);
}
```

Comment: But territory.name is not working here

Comment: @SFDC_Learner - **Define "Not Working"**

Comment: It simply says Territory.name not valid